# ReactJS array map

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, dictionary

I am trying to print array elements in a table. The array is stored in data.  While using map() I keep getting
"cannot read property of null" error

the code is

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component{

constructor(){
    super();

    this.state={
        data:[
            {
                "id":1,
                "name":"Foo",
                "age":"20"
            },
            {
                "id":2,
                "name":"Bar",
                "age":"30"
            },
            {
                "id":3,
                "name":"Baz",
                "age":"0"
            }    
        ]
    }

}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <Header />
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    {this.state.data.map((person,i)=><TableRow key={i} data={person} />)}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
 }
}

class Header extends React.Component{
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>
    );
  }
 }

class TableRow extends React.Component{
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <tr>
                <td>{this.state.data.id}</td>
                <td>{this.state.data.name}</td>
                <td>{this.state.data.age}</td>
            </tr>
        </div>
    );
 }
}

class Content extends React.Component{
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <h2>Content</h2>
            <p>The content text!!</p>
        </div>
    );
}
 }

 export default App;
```

I am trying to send the data to TableRow class. Help me fix this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `TableRow` component, use `props` instead of `state`. You are passing the data to the compoment from outside, that's what the props are for. You'd use state only if you'd set it directly from the component. And, of course, the state is separate for each component.

```
class TableRow extends React.Component{
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <tr>
                <td>{this.props.data.id}</td>
                <td>{this.props.data.name}</td>
                <td>{this.props.data.age}</td>
            </tr>
        </div>
    );
 }
}
```